# Get container entity using child id

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I want to get the **branch** object in which **leaf**(using it's ID) belongs to

What is the right approach to get the *branch* given that I only have the *leaf* ID? I thought of looping through all the branches in the db and get the one which contain the leaf ID which looks bad

```
@Entity
public class Branch {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "branch_id")
  private List<Leaf> leaves
}

@Entity 
public class Leaf {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  private String name;
}

@Service
public class BranchService {
  private final BranchRepository branchRepository;

  @Autowired
  public BranchService(BranchRepository branchRepository) {
    branchRepository = branchRepository;
  }

  public Tree getBranchByLeaf(Long leafId){
     // ??
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public interface BranchRepository extends JpaRepository<Branch, Long> {
    @Query("select b from Branch b join b.leaves l where l.id = ?1")
    List<Branch> getByLeafId(Long leafId);
}

@Service
public class BranchService {

    private final BranchRepository branchRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BranchService(BranchRepository branchRepository) {
        branchRepository = branchRepository;
    }

    public List<Branch> getByLeafId(Long leafId){
        return branchRepository.getByLeafId(Long leafId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you miss '... b.leaves l ...'?

Comment: @LemuelNabong Try now - I missed an alias 'b' after `Branch`... )